# ASP NET MVC 4. RedirectToRouteResult in custom exception filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I has a custom exception filter attribute:

```
 public class RedirectOnErrorAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter {

        #region IExceptionFilter Members

        public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) {
            if(filterContext.ExceptionHandled) return;

            filterContext.Controller.TempData["Exception"] = filterContext.Exception;
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new {area = "Desktop", controller = "Exception", action = "HandleError" }));
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

The Action 'HandleError' of 'ExceptionController' contains some business logic.
In 'HandleError' action

```
public ActionResult HandleError() {
        Exception ex = (Exception)TempData["Exception"];
        logger.Log(ex);
}
```

In ex variable I always get exception with message 'Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.'

How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may try looking at the `ex.InnerException`. If it is not null it might contain more useful information.

Comment: ex.InnerException = {"Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions."}

Comment: Well, I hope you didn't put the `RedirectOnErrorAttribute` on a child action or on a controller that contains child actions. You cannot redirect from child actions.